# c# confused about base class inheritance

Tags: c#, binary-tree, multiple-inheritance

I am confused as to exactly how classes inherit methods from each other. I already understand inheritance from base classes, there is however, certain code from an example that I do not understand. It involves searching a Binary tree and I could not find any resources that better explain how the code is inherited.

My aim is to understand it so that I can use it to also searched a linkedlist.

If any one can refer me to any relevant literature that explains this particular area I would be grateful.

I have highlighted the code section that I dont really yet understand how it is inhertied. The specific section is posted first:

```
public Company Read(string bezeichnung)
{
    return stri.Search(new Company() { Bezeichnung = bezeichnung });
}
```

Entire program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace CompanySearch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\chris\Desktop\algo\fuckit\unternehmen.csv", Encoding.Default);
            Companies stri2 = new Companies(r);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Unternehmensbezeichnung eingeben: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                    break;
                //Company konk = stri2.Read(name);
                Company konk = new Company();
                konk = stri2.Read(name);
                if (konk == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Unternehmen nicht gefunden!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(konk + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Companies
    {
        private BinaryTree<Company> stri = new BinaryTree<Company>();
        public Companies(StreamReader rp)
        {
            // Spaltenüberschriften auslesen
            //var tokens = rp.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ';' });
            //if (tokens.Length != 3)
            //    throw new ArgumentException("More than 3 columns in company file");
            string line;
            while ((line = rp.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var tokens = line.Split(new char[]{';'});
                //tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                stri.Add(new Company()
                {Bezeichnung = tokens[0], Branche = tokens[1], Ort = tokens[2]});
            }

            rp.Close();
        }

        public Company Read(string bezeichnung)
        {
            return stri.Search(new Company()
            {Bezeichnung = bezeichnung});
        }
    }

    public class Company : IComparable<Company>
    {
        public string Bezeichnung
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Branche
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Ort
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Company other)
        {
            return Bezeichnung.CompareTo(other.Bezeichnung);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Bezeichnung: {0}\tBranche: {1}\tOrt: {2}", Bezeichnung, Branche, Ort);
        }
    }

    public enum TraverseModeEnum
    {
        PreOrder,
        PostOrder,
        InOrder,
        ReverseInOrder
    }

    public class BinaryTree<T>
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        private sealed class Node<TNode>
            where TNode : IComparable<TNode> // TNode muss IComparable implementieren
        {
            public TNode Item
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public Node<TNode> Left
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public Node<TNode> Right
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int CompareTo(TNode other)
            {
                return Item.CompareTo(other);
            }
        }

        private Node<T> root;
        public int Count
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public TraverseModeEnum TraverseMode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public BinaryTree()
        {
            TraverseMode = TraverseModeEnum.PreOrder;
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            if (root == null)
                root = new Node<T>()
                {Item = item};
            else
                addTo(root, item);
            Count++;
        }

        public void AddRange(T[] items)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
                Add(item);
        }

        private void addTo(Node<T> node, T item)
        {
            if (item.CompareTo(node.Item) < 0)
            {
                if (node.Left == null)
                    node.Left = new Node<T>()
                    {Item = item};
                else
                    addTo(node.Left, item);
            }
            else
            {
                if (node.Right == null)
                    node.Right = new Node<T>()
                    {Item = item};
                else
                    addTo(node.Right, item);
            }
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            Node<T> node = root;
            while (node != null)
            {
                int c = node.Item.CompareTo(item);
                if (c == 0)
                    return true;
                if (c > 0)
                    node = node.Left;
                else
                    node = node.Right;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public T Search(T item)
        {
            Node<T> node = root;
            while (node != null)
            {
                int c = node.Item.CompareTo(item);
                if (c == 0)
                    return node.Item;
                if (c > 0)
                    node = node.Left;
                else
                    node = node.Right;
            }

            return default (T);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            root = null;
            Count = 0;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "";
            int level = 0;
            traverse(root, level, ref s);
            return s;
        }

        private void traverse(Node<T> node, int level, ref string s)
        {
            if (node == null)
                return;
            bool reverse = TraverseMode == TraverseModeEnum.ReverseInOrder;
            if (TraverseMode == TraverseModeEnum.PreOrder)
                s += "".PadLeft(level, ' ') + node.Item.ToString() + "\n";
            traverse(reverse ? node.Right : node.Left, level + 2, ref s);
            if (TraverseMode == TraverseModeEnum.InOrder || TraverseMode == TraverseModeEnum.ReverseInOrder)
                s += "".PadLeft(level, ' ') + node.Item.ToString() + "\n";
            traverse(reverse ? node.Left : node.Right, level + 2, ref s);
            if (TraverseMode == TraverseModeEnum.PostOrder)
                s += "".PadLeft(level, ' ') + node.Item.ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was it really necessary to include all 257 lines of code for your example?

Comment: You should avoid inheritance unless you know exactly what you are doing. There is a nice saying, Composition over Inheritance from the GoF book in design patterns. The reason is because even though polymorphism is great... its hard. Try and do your code using Dependency Injection as that follows the principles SOLID

Comment: there's no inheritance going on here as far as I can see. the `Company` class implements the interface `IComparable<Company>`. see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2 . Interface implementation is not the same thing as inheritance (although the bare syntax in the class declaration is similar). And the code you've posted as being the bit you don't understand doesn't seem to make use of any of the methods of that interface. It's a bit unclear precisely what you don't understand. Can you clarify _precisely_ which aspect is confusing you?

Comment: Oh wow OK. Confusing Inheritance with Interfaces. I hope this is not a real world app....

Comment: Please do not provide your entire code-base, but only the **relevant** parts of your code, that show what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck.

Comment: P.S. you've tagged this with multiple-inheritance but I don't see any example of multiple inheritance in the code. Did you think there was one? Whereabouts? C# doesn't support multiple inheritance through classes btw (you may know that already). A similar effect can sometimes be achieved by implementing multiple interfaces but that isn't happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `BinaryTree<T>` down in the code demands that `T` must implement `IComparable<T>`. Lots of list-ish classes make similar demands. If a type implements `IComparable<T>` it means two instances of a class can be compared to each other with the `ComparetTo( T t1, T t2 )` method. This method returns an indication of which `T` is *greater than, less than, or equal to* the other. Realize that the *greater than, less than, or equal to* is entirely up to the type that implements the interface. It's principally used for sorting or otherwise locating things in a tree, list, or other structure based on the comparison.

Implementing an interface looks like class inheritance. The syntax is the same...but it's more like a contract, since an interface has no code to inherit. If you make a class that goes like:

```
class MyClass: IComparable<MyClass>
{
  //--> stuff
}
```

...then you're obligated to have a publicly visible method with the signature:

```
int CompareTo( MyClass a, MyClass b )
{
   //--> look at the two instances and make a determination...
}
```

The method can use any characteristics of the class to determine what makes `a` *greater than, less than, or equal to* `b`...and thereby control how it's going to be placed into a structure.

A class can inherit from only one other class...but it can implement as many interfaces as it needs. This is what, I'm guessing, looks like multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation

Answer (score 1):

a. There is no real inheritance in your code. Only the implementation of a standard interface,  `IComparable<T>`. Implementing an interface is sometimes called inheritance but it is not the same. In this case it forces `Company` to implement the `CompareTo()` method.

b. The code you have a question about just creates a temporary object. You can rewrite it to something that might be easier to understand:

```
//return stri.Search(new Company() { Bezeichnung = bezeichnung });
var tempCompany = new Company() { Bezeichnung = bezeichnung };
return stri.Search(tempCompany);
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated